# Why does Magento append same url?

Tags: magento

I have a problem that my Magento installation is appending the URL to the original URL.

```
https://petshop.vetoquinol.de/aktuelle-angebote.htmlhttps://petshop.vetoquinol.de/aktuelle-angebote.html
```

Can you help fixing this please?

Thanks.

Comment: And where? In which section? Some examples?

Comment: Can you describe your issue?